# How to extract Windows user profile SIDs from registry into text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a task coming up where I have to manually enter an `HKEY_USER` key value and string value for every single Windows profile on all computers. This could take some time. I have leant to automate them all, or at least, some of the processes.

I have the adding key process (from a list of `sids.txt`) working:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("SIDS.txt") do (
    REG ADD "%%A\create\key\here" /f
    REG ADD "%%A\create\key\here" /t REG_SZ /d "add string value here" /f
)
pause
```

To further speed things up I was hoping to get some help getting the SID from each user profile from here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

For each SID listed e.g.:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-2686047782-4092528985-2296408390-1413
```

Within the keys there is a profile-image-path value which contains the name of the Windows user profile.

What I would like to be able to do is pump the Windows profile name and the sid into a text file formatted like the following, then I can edit fairly quickly, remove non-Windows user profile entries (like default or system accounts) and run my working code above against the listings - edited to have just a list of SIDS like in the working code above.

```
S-1-5-21-2686047782-4092528985-2296408390-1413  mickey.mouse 
S-1-5-21-2686047782-4092528985-2296408390-1411  Donald.duck
```

Comment: so you just require the SID? i.e `S-1-5-21-2686047782-4092528985-2296408390-1413`

Comment: ideally with user names so I can omit non user profiles from the final run of the script  - thanks

Comment: thanks that's perfect !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method would beto do it with `wmic useraccount` query:

```
wmic useraccount get name,sid | findstr /vi "SID">somefile.txt
type somefile.txt
```

This would list every account and redirect output to a file called `somefile.txt` and it will simply `type` the file to show you the content of the file.

Another way is to see if the userprofile directory exists. which should eliminate system accounts.

```
@for /f "delims=" %i in ('wmic useraccount get name^,sid ^| findstr /vi "SID"') do @for /F %a in ("%i") do if exist "C:\users\%a" @echo(%i>>somefile.txt
```

Comment: This, as you've stated, lists every account; however the question asks to exclude `non windows user profile entries (like default or system accounts`.

Comment: Gerhard, I have deleted my answer, you may now make your edit to meet the OP's criteria, and I will tidy up my comments appropriately.

Comment: @Compo why did you delete your answer if it met the requirement for op?

Comment: Gerhard, I have absolutely no interest in points, reputation or arguing with those who do! BTW, in your latest edit, i.e. bottom most code, it is quite often likely that the Administrator account would still be retrieved, not that it was specifically mentioned, but worthy of note.